# Are Matlab Matrices transferred pass-by-value or pass-by-reference?

Tags: matlab, matrix, pass-by-reference

I'm new at Matlab. You may find this question silly but I really wonder if the statement below is a pass-by-value operation or pass-by-reference operation.

```
I = imread('logo.png');
binaryImage = im2bw(I, 0.4);
Itemp = binaryImage;
```

Does the `Itemp` is a new matrix whose values are copied from `binaryImage`, or it is just a pointer to the `binaryImage`?

Comment: Why are you worried about the internals of Matlab? From the programmer's point of view it is a copy of the array. Internally it is probably a reference counted object that will make a copy if you  modify it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's pass by reference, until you modify `Itemp`.

When you modify `Itemp` matlab will copy `binaryImage` to `Itemp` and then modify it.

I made some interesting tests a while a go.
If you do:

```
A=rand(100);B=A;C=B;D=A;E=B;
```

only one copy is kept in memory. If you modify `A`

```
A(1)=1;
```

Then, matlab make **one** new copy of the matrix for the new `A`, and the variables `B`,`C`,`D`,`E` still point to the matrix of the old `A`.

Answer (score 13):

Matlab uses a [copy-on-write](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/05/10/memory-management-for-functions-and-variables/) strategy

Comment: this is more important, actually